# Set Diffrent DataContext to an Element in a ControlTemplate in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, contenttemplate

I can't get any further.

My structure looks like this:

```
ViewModel (Class)
   Property Number (Class, iValue)
                Value, InputValidationInfo, etc.
   Property Icon (Class, iValue)
                Value, InputValidationInfo, etc.
```

The DataContext of the page is the ViewModel. There are input fields on the page. These are assigned to one of the iValues (Number, Icon). All input fields have a ContentTemplate. The ContentTemplate contains some elements which has bindings to the properties of the iValue-class.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <DockPanel>
            <Border Width="10" Background="{Binding InputValidation, Converter={StaticResource InputValidationToBrushConverter}}" Margin="0">
                <Border.ToolTip>
                    <ToolTip Visibility="{Binding InputValidationInfoCount, Converter={StaticResource CountToVisibleConverter}}" >
                                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding InputValidationInfo}"/>
                         </ToolTip>
                     </Border.ToolTip>
                 </Border>
                 <Border x:Name="ContentBorder" Margin="1">
                 <Grid>
                     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                     <ContentPresenter Margin="5 1 0 1" x:Name="myButtonContent" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextElement.Foreground="{StaticResource ButtonForegroundBrush}"/>
                     <StackPanel x:Name="Buttons" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="Collapsed">
                         <Button x:Name="ResetButton" Style="{StaticResource styleInputBoxSubButton}" Content="{StaticResource symbolCancel}" FontFamily="{StaticResource symbolCancelFF}" Command="{Binding ResetValueCommand}"/>
                     </StackPanel>
                 </Grid>
             </Border>
         </DockPanel>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

And this is how it looks like:

```
<Button x:Name="btnIcon" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" DataContext="{Binding Icon}"
    Style="{StaticResource styleInputButton}" MinHeight="37"
    FontFamily="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource NumberToUserIconFontFamilyConverter}}"
    Content="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource NumberToUserIconConverter}}"
    Click="IconButton_Click"/>
```

[image]

My problem are the click events. The small [X] button is bound to the iValue classes with an ICommand. This works well. I can set the iCommand as binding in the ControlTemplate, because this is always the same iValue-property (ResetValueCommand).

But, a click of the "rest" of the actual button should call a method in the ViewModel. And the name of this method is not always the same. It cannot set in the ContentTemplate.

I cannot bind the command to the ViewModel, because the DataContext is already the iValue.
I have tried to use the Click event. But this event is also triggered by clicking the [X]-button.

This button should be used often. An elegant solution is needed. The most simple thing would be if I could specify the data context and binding for a particular element in the ContentTemplate in page-XAML. Or specify the click event of an element in the ContentTemplate in page-XAML.

Comment: I think based on this that maybe you need to have a separate viewmodel for the button?  Then the button could have its own context distinct from the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cannot bind the command to the ViewModel, because the DataContext is already the iValue ...

You can specify a source for the binding regardless of its `DataContext`:

```
<Button x:Name="btnIcon" ...
        Command="{Binding DataContext.CommandPropertyOfViewModel, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Page}}"/>
```